# Django adding tiny-mce

Tags: django

Please suggest the best way to add tinymce to django admin area. Is it possible to add it by extending /admin/change_form.html in my template directory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way in my opinion is [django-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/).

Its awesome and super easy to integrate into your project, plus you can add [django-filebrowser](http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/) in easily for image uploading.

Comment: You can't easily add in django-filebrowser, at least, not without installing Grappelli, which is an awfully big change to make.

Comment: [django-filebrowser-no-grappelli](https://github.com/wardi/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli) is a great solution if you do not want to use Grappelli, I don't use Grappelli and this is what I do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion, but I want to do it manually,and avoid applications, as I will know more about django , while doing it.. in the mean time I added YUI to admin area ;) as it doesn't need any url rewrites..please tell me the manual way to integrating it ..

Comment: If you want to avoid using the django-tinymce app you could try the instructions [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor) which is a more "manual" way to do it.

Comment: cool, didn't know about django-filebrowser-no-grappelli - thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the tiny_mce.js library somehwere in your media folder. For example in js/tiny_mce/
2. Then (for django 1.2) you need to create a custom model admin in your_app/admin.py. Add a class Media with js attribute to it. Example:

   > ```
   > from django.contrib import admin
   > from myapp.models import MyModel
   >
   > class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   >     class Media:
   >         js = ('js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
   >               'js/admin/textareas.js',)
   >
   > admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
   > ```
3. In media/js/admin/textareas.js you can add your call to tinyMCE.init. Example:

   > ```
   > tinyMCE.init({
   >         mode : "textareas",
   >         theme : "advanced"
   > });
   > ```

That's it. Javascript is included automatically. No need to overwrite admin templates.

**Note**: One thing I forget to mention that in this case it only applies to the  admin for MyModel. If you need the same functionality for all yout model's, simply register this custom ModelAdmin to them or add Media classes to exising ModelAdmin classes.

Answer (score 2):

django-tinymce is the way to go. You can use pip to install it. You use it on model fields like so:

```
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models
class Foo(models.Model):
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="You can use HTML markup - be careful!")
```

If you are using South for DB migrations you need to help it out with this line:

```
add_introspection_rules([], ["^tinymce.models.HTMLField"])
```

Works like a charm!